# Bluetooth no inicia en Ubuntu 18.04 después de actualización

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

Estoy usando Ubuntu 18.04 y al reiniciar el sistema no consigo que arranque el servicio de bluetooth. He intentado hacer el restart desde el terminal:

```
service bluetooth restart
```

Tampoco se inicia.

En el log he observado que está activo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la configuración no da la opción a activarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por más que reinicie no se activa. Esto está pasando en un equipo Dell XPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de buscar, me acordé que hace un tiempo me pasó exactamente lo mismo con la Wi-Fi.

> La solución en estos casos es hacer un **hard-reset** al portátil.
>   (Mantener pulsado el botón de power durante unos segundos).

Y milagrosamente ha vuelto a funcionar.

Saludos! :)

Answer (score -1):

No consigo ubicar el problema de forma concreta, pero creo que una de las posibles soluciones es que realizes una actualizacion del sistema completa :

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

Una vez actualizado el sistema, cuando inicies realiza este comando para fijar que el servicio se levante automaticamente, en caso de que no lo tengas asi.

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
```

Y despues por ultimo vuelve a reiniciar.

Comment: Si te fijas abajo ya he resuelto la pregunta, aunque gracias por la aportación :)